# When listing just a last name would it be "Name, Jr." or "Name Jr"?

Tags: commas, surnames

When listing names by just a **last name**, which is correct:

- `Surname, Jr.`
- `Surname Jr.`

I'd like to know if the comma is required in this context or not.

Comment: It depends on the style manual you're forced to use. Otherwise, there are no unequivocal punctuation, spelling, or grammatical rules in English. It's a free-for-all language spoken and written by millions of native speakers who are sure that their idiolects are perfectly standard, idiomatic, and acceptable to all other native speakers. _Write like you speak_ is only half the story. The other half is _Edit what you write for clarity and brevity_. Most writers forget the 2nd half. Commas are unpopular today. _Name, Jr._ is traditional. _Name Jr._ is the new normal.

Comment: -1 Please show research results. Close Not Constructive: answers will be a matter of opinion.

Comment: @ΜετάEd what search results?

Comment: Research results, meaning what references you consulted before asking here, what they said, etc. See the [faq] and the article it links to about asking a good question.

Comment: @ΜετάEd I wouldn't know where to search for this particular question, that is why I asked here at [English.SE].

Comment: Simply trying the Google search `[ punctuating jr ]` supplies a broad spectrum of advice on the question, ranging from the discredited (Strunk & White) to the respected and widely used (APA style). If that had not answered your question, it would at least have been a starting point for a more specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit of a general reference question, but I'll go ahead an answer it here, because the "right" answer seems to be in a state of flux. From [Chicago Manual of Style Online](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/CMS_FAQ/Jr.Sr.III/Jr.Sr.III02.html):

[image]

EDIT: If you are only listing by **last name**, I think you would omit the suffix altogether.  After all, John Smith, Sr., and John Smith, Jr., and John Smith III all have the same last name: Smith.  John David Jones, the son of John Daniel Jones, is not John Jones, Jr., so both of them would be listed as Jones; I think the Smiths would be listed the same way, although I don't have an authoritative reference to base that on.

Comment: It's the same in *The Associated Press Stylebook* (AP style).

Answer (score -2):

Your question make no sense. If there are 3 people to be listed then you are proposing:

- John Doe Jr would be listed as Doe Jr.
- Jim Doe would be listed as Doe
- Jason Doe Sr. would be Doe Sr.

Comment: In the situation we are working in, we don't care about the first name at all.

Comment: @CyberSkull: Any reason why you didn't offer that particular nugget of information in your original question?

Comment: @J.R. I said "just a last name".

Comment: @CyberSkull: Ah! So you did! _Mea culpa._ I think that highlighting the question as you did in your edit might help. Thanks for clarifying.